# Alterar src de imagens através jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagem

Estou a usar o plugin [Animated Responsive Image Grid](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/) e quero alterar o src das imagens através de Javascript/Jquery.

Código html:

```
<div id="ri-grid" class="ri-grid ri-grid-size-1 ri-shadow">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/1.jpg" alt="Whatever works"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/2.jpg" alt="Anything else"/></a></li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

e tenho um array de links de imagens com tamanho variável

```
vectorImagens=[]
```

O objectivo é alterar o `src="images/medium/1.jpg"` para `src=vectorImagens[0]`, e `src="images/medium/2.jpg"` para `src=vectorImagens[1]` e etc

Comment: Veja essa pergunta, é basicamente a mesma coisa.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5754/como-trocar-o-img-src-de-uma-imagem-pequena-por-uma-imagem-grande/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você precisa é de correr um código que muda o atributo `src` a cada imagem.

Uma vez que você já tem um `vectorImagens`, use assim:

```
$('#ri-grid img').each(function(i){
    vectorImagens[i] && this.setAttribute('src', vectorImagens[i]); 
});
// Explicação:
// Iterar todas as imagens e usar o parametro i (index) que o jQuery dá para ir 
// buscar o correspondente à array vectorImagens
```

No caso de haver menos imagens no `vectorImagens` do que elementos `img`, pode usar assim:

```
var contador = 0;
$('#ri-grid img').each(function(){
    if(!vectorImagens[contador]) contador = 0;
    this.setAttribute('src', vectorImagens[contador]);
    contador ++;
});
// Explicação:
// Iterar todas as imagens e usar o parametro contador para ir 
// buscar o correspondente à array vectorImagens. 
// No caso de não existir tal imagem, o if() dá true e faz reset ao contador.
// Assim a iteração de imagens continua mas a imagem buscada volta ao inicio 
// da array de imagens (vectorImagens)
```

### [**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DKJTc/)

Opção só com vanilla JS:

```
var contador = 0;
var imagens = document.getElementById("ri-grid").getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < imagens.length; i++) {
    if (!vectorImagens[contador]) contador = 0;
    imagens[i].setAttribute('src', vectorImagens[contador]);
    contador++;
};
```

### [**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8SHZJ/2/)

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio a sua solução foi muito útil!

Answer (score 3):

É simples, utilizando jQuery você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
var vectorImagens = ["images/medium/3.jpg","images/medium/4.jpg"];//exemplo
var len = vectorImagens.length; //tamanho do vectorImagens
var imagens = $('#ri-grid ul li a img'); //os elementos img
for(var i=0; i < len; i++){ //percorre o tamanho do vectorImagens
    imagens.eq(i).attr('src', vectorImagens[i]);
}
```

## [Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bMQ6W/2/)

Comment: Obrigado @Paulo Roberto